# Calculate power spectral density in R but define output length

Tags: r, signals, signal-processing

I have 3 different signals. I want to calculate their spectral density and then do some extra analysis. The 3 signals have different lengths so when I find spectral density the output is of different lengths. I have tried:

```
pspectrum; eegfit; fft
```

but none of them seems to have such an option. In MATLAB this was fairly straightforward

```
fft(signal,output_length)
```

so I think I am missing a basic function here....

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/60322/matlab-and-r-functions-for-fft-n-point-fft-and-dimension-issue

It turns out that fft(x,n) in MATLAB just pads with 0 or truncates depending on the size of x.

EDIT: Just to clarify that MATLAB truncates or pads x (input signal) and not the fft output (I found out the hard way). So in R you have to do the following:

1. Fix the size of input signal
2. Run fft as usual